# Push notifications for flutter chat app without firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there any way to create push notifications with Flutter without using Firebase (FCM)? Would it be possible to have a background job that has a socket connection to the message backend to receive the notification?

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do deliver messages to apps that are not actively being used without FCM/APNS, as that would require the process to keep a socket connection open even during this inactivity. The underlying operating systems (iOS and Android) either don't allow this to begin with, or actively kill such open connections after a short period of the app being inactive.

Comment: If the os kills all open connections, what connection does f. e. FCM use to the flutter app?

Comment: These connections are natively integrated into iOS and Android. You can "bypass" FCM on iOS by using APNS directly, for example.

Comment: Yup, @Mäddin, that's correct both on it being in the OS and why I mentioned APNS in my answer. I should've been more clear there, I realize now on its role. Btw: FCM also bypasses APNS (using its own socket transport) for message delivery when the app is active, but that wasn't the scope of the use-case here. Finally: there are also higher-level products that deliver messages, but these build on top of APNS/FCM to do the actual delivery, so you'd still be using those under the hood.